# Looking for a way to get Simple Registration add-on to send details to Campaign Monitor list subscription

Tags: members, campaignmonitor, signup

I'm working on a site that uses Simple Registration to handle user registrations (we needed the facility to assign people to a particular group on sign up).

I also need this process to involve adding the user to a mailing list on Campaign Monitor.

I've tried using the excellent Campaigner, but this doesn't seem to work with Simple Registration. I'm not sure why at the moment but it seems the 2 add-ons don't play nicely.

Has anyone got experience of this or have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try swithing to Freemember of Stand-Alone Member Register for registration. Both have option to assign people to certain group.